# How should I structure my schema so I can save the data correctly?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am creating a shop application where the shop has categories.

`sizes` and `products` belong to `category`

If I create a new `product`, the `Categories` are displayed as a selectbox, and I can select the desired category from the available options. This works fine.

As the `sizes` belongs to `category`, I want to display the `sizes` associated with selected category as input boxes. where I want to enter the prices of each `size` of the `product`

I have an Ajax request which return the sizes as json. Now I am not sure how to display the sizes in the product add template. Should I put it within the same form? Where will I save the prices?

How should the prices table structure look?

Comment: Can you share more information? It seems to me the sizes and prices would apply to the product, not the category. But it's not clear what your data intentions are.

Comment: Can you please check the schema at
http://dbdsgnr.appspot.com/app#agdkYmRzZ25ycg8LEgZTY2hlbWEYmuCEAQw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the requirements, this will be a bit difficult as your question is very broad and I am not certain the schema is correct. If the schema is not correct, it would explain why you are struggling.

There are columns that don't quite make sense to me. For example, you have a `category_id` on the `product` and the `size`. Then you have a `price` table that links `product` and `size`, but do you require a contraint that the `size.category_id` match the `product.category_id`?

Knowing what I know about databases and shopping carts, this is how I would write the schema:

```
Categories
    id
    name
    description
    active
    created
    modified

Sizes
    id
    name

Products
    id
    name
    description
    price
    active
    offered
    created
    modified

Categories_Products
    id
    category_id
    product_id

Products_Sizes
    id
    product_id
    size_id
    price

Toppings
    id
    name
    description
    price
    active
    created
    modified

Categories_Toppings
    id
    category_id
    toppings_id

Sizes_Toppings
    id
    size_id
    topping_id
    price
```

**Explanation**

- The initial `Product` will have a base price.
- Each `Product` can be associated to N `Categories` through a HABTM
  relationship.
- Each `Product` can be associated to N `Sizes` through a HABTM
  relationship.
- The `Product_Size` HABTM table will store the price adjustment for
  the size.
- The initial `Topping` will have a base price.
- Each `Topping` can be associated to N `Categories` through a HABTM
  relationship.
- Each `Topping` can be associated to N `Sizes` through a HABTM
  relationship.
- The `Size_Topping` HABTM table will store the price adjustment for
  the size.

Comment: Thank you again for the detailed response. I still have a bit confusion, what I wanted to achive by assigning Sizes to Categories was that each product which belongs to a specific Category must have exactly the same number of sizes. And one product can belong to Single Category.

Comment: The problem is there is no way to constrain the database forcing each product to have data on every size because you are using a different table for the sizes. So you ultimately will still need to write some validation on the code to check that ALL sizes were used. Then what happens when a new size is added for a category? Do ALL products break because now there is a new size but no corresponding data for the given product? You may need to revisit the requirements and share those so there is clearer understanding. Right now this question is too broad to answer.